# Can a matrix transformation ever make a linearly dependent matrix linearly independent?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I'm curious. Can ANY matrix transformation make some matrix with its columns linearly independent, or with an empty kernel, linearly independent? For example, if A is a linearly dependent matrix, and B any matrix, could BA ever come out to be linearly independent?

Comment: Well, the zero matrix of the due degree always makes any matrix's rows/columns linearly dependent.

Comment: How about $f (X) = A X + B$, where $B$ has full rank?

Answer (score 4):

No it can not:
$$
A \in K^{m\times n}, B \in K^{p\times m}
$$
$A$ is linear dependent, so there exist $\lambda_k\in K$ not all equal to $0$ with
$$
\sum_{k=1}^n \lambda_k a_k = 0.
$$
where $A=(a_1,a_2,\ldots,a_n)$ or: there is a non-zero vector $x_0 = (\lambda_k)\ne 0$ with 
$$
A x_0 = 0.
$$
For $BA$ we have
$$
(BA)x_0 = B(Ax_0) = B 0 = 0
$$
so regardless of the choice of $B$ the vector $x_0$ is a non-zero kernel vector for $BA$, so $BA$ can not be linear independent.

Answer (score 0):

Let the matrices $A$ and $B$ be given. Suppose the columns of $A$ are the column vectors $A_i$ where $i$ runs over the number of columns, let that number be $k$.

Now,  $BA = [BA_1|BA_2|\ldots BA_k]$

So, your question boils down to asking can $B$ act on the set of linearly independent vectors $\{A_1, A_2, \ldots A_k\}$ such that the resulting set $\{BA_1, BA_2, \ldots BA_k\}$ is linearly dependent.

The answer is yes, let $B$ be the transformation that mixes the columns of $A$, for example, define $BA_1 = A_1+A_2$ and $BA_i = A_i$ for $i \geq 2$

Comment: I was asking the opposite - if A, a linearly dependent matrix, could become BA, a linearly independent matrix.

Answer (score 0):

Here's another proof. Suppose that you have vectors $v_1, v_2,... v_n$ which are linearly dependent. Since the transformation makes these vectors linearly independent, then $a_1T(v_1) + a_2T(v_2) + \dots a_nT(v_n) = 0$ has only trivial solutions. If $v_1, v_2,\dots v_n$ are linearly dsependent, then there exist non-trivial solutions to $a_1v_1 + a_2v_2 +\dots+a_nv_n = 0$. If we apply the transformation T to both sides, then there are non trivial solutions to $$T(a_1v_1 + a_2v_2 + \dots + a_nv_n) = 0 = T(a_1v_1) + T(a_2v_2) +\dots+T(a_nv_n) = a_1T(v_1) + a_2T(v_2) + \dots+ a_nT(v_n)$$
which results in a contradiction. Thus, if the vectors after the transformation are linearly independent, then they must be linearly independent beforehand.